# JavaScript function retrieving data from excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, activex, activexobject

I need a help with my JS function. What I want is to retrieve data from my Excel to the form. The data depends on 2 parameters. The function I wrote is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function retrieve (){
var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");  
  var book=excel.Workbooks.Open(MY PATH HERE );
  var sheet=book.Sheet.Item(1);

  var one =document.getElementbyId("one").value
  var two=document.getElementbyID("two").value
  var range=sheet.getActiveRange();
  var numRows =range.getNumRows();
  var numCols=range.getNumCols();


  for(var i=1; i<=numRows;i++){
    for(var j=1;j<=numCols;j++){
      if(range.getCell(i,3).getValue()==one && range.getCell(5,j).getValue()==two){

       var name=range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
         document.getElementById('nazwisko').value = name;
      }
    }

  }
}

</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Would anyone be kind to help me with this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about this code isn't working and what have you already done to try and solve it?

Comment: I use this function in a button in my html form. After clicking it I get the alert " An ActiveX control might be unsafe to interacts with other parts of the page". Then the page cannot be dispalyed anymore.